# Como colocar duas cores distintas em um chat, a cor do texto do usuário tem que ser x e a cor do texto do bot tem quer ser y

Tags: javascript

No html tenho este código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="chat.css"
<html>
<head>
<title>Assistente Virtual</title>
<h1>Informe sua dúvida que nosso assistente virtual irá te ajudar</h1>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>




    <textarea style="font-size: 20px;" cols="50" rows="200" id="resposta" >
        Olá me chamo Natália e sou sua assistente virtual, como posso te ajudar? (para os comandos digita /cmd)
    </textarea>


<p id="mudarcor">Para agendamento de dia e hora envie (1)</p>

<p><input type="text" id="pergunta" placeholder="Olá, Como posso te ajudar?" autofocus></p>

<button  id = 'btn' onclick="enviar()">Enviar</button>

<script src='chat.js'></script>

<center>

</body>

</html>
```

No JavaScript este código:

```
var bot ='Assistente Virtual: ';
var user = 'Usuário: ';
// script para funcionar ao apertar o enter
var input = document.getElementById("pergunta");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {             //falta add um evento de click ao o usuário clikar em enviar e limpar
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        document.getElementById("btn").click();
        erase_sent();

        }
});
//função pra limpar o input ao usuário depois de enviar
function erase_sent()
{
  var limpo = null;
  document.getElementById('pergunta').value = limpo;
}



// Falas para o bot
var resp_padrao = ['Para agendamento de dia e hora envie (1), Se deseja saber qual dia o seu serviço estará pronto envie (2), Se deseja remarcar o dia do seu serviço tecle (3), Se deseja fazer o pagamento e gerar um boleto tecle (4), Se deseja falar com um de nossos atendentes tecle (5)'];
var resp_oi = ['Olá? Como posso te ajudar', 'Sou uma assistente virtual pronta para lhe ajudar'];
var resp_ale = ['humm... não entendi', 'Você pode ser mais específico por favor?', 'Desculpa mas não entendi'];
var resp_formal = ['Por favor, digite uma das opções acima', 'Só consigo te direcionar se vc digitar umas das opções acima', 'Estou me esforçando mas não consigo te entender']

  // temperatura por window prompt
  function temperatura()
    {
      document.getElementById('resposta').value = bot + 'Você quer saber a temperatura de onde ?';
      var winprom = window.prompt (bot + 'Qual cidade deseja a informação de temperatura ?');
      window.open('https://www.google.com.br/search?q=temperatura+' + winprom );
  }
/*
  // Falas Geradas por um loop
  function fala_sozinho()
  {

    for(i = 0 ; i < 10; i++)
    {
      var falas = resp_ale[Math.floor(Math.random() * resp_ale.length)];          //Math.floor(Math.random(); retorna um número aleatório entre os valores especificados, ex.: Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
      document.getElementById('resposta').value += falas;                        //retornará um número aleatório entre 1 e 100, nesse caso se tratando de strings eu fiz com que retornasse a variável resp_ale.length
                                                                                //então dessa forma irá retornar frases aleatórias
    }
  }
  */

  // Gera data e hora atual
  function data_atual()
  {
    var today = new Date();
    var data_final = today.getDate() + '/' + today.getMonth() + '/' + today.getFullYear(); // data
    var hour_final = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() ; // hora
    document.getElementById('resposta').value += bot + 'São ' +  hour_final + ' do dia ' + data_final + '' ;
  }


  function mudarCor(){
    //var cor = document.getElementById('pergunta').value;
    //cor = document.getElementById('pergunta').style.color = 'red';
  };

  // func principal
  function enviar()
  {
    var padrao = resp_padrao[Math.floor(Math.random() * resp_padrao.length)]; 
    var formal = resp_formal[Math.floor(Math.random() * resp_formal.length)];
    var input = document.getElementById("pergunta").value;
    var rand = resp_oi[Math.floor(Math.random() * resp_oi.length)];


     /**document.getElementById('resposta').value -> este .value é valor que estou atribuindo ao html para que o usuário 
       * veja, estou pegando a id resposta que é o textarea do html e atribuindo valores para que estes sejam repassados
       * ao usuário.
       */


    if (input.indexOf('oi') != -1 || input.indexOf('olá') != -1 || input.indexOf('preciso de ajuda') != -1 || input.indexOf('ei') != -1 ) // != -> O operador de desigualdade retorna true (verdade) se os operandos não são iguais
      {
        document.getElementById('resposta').value = user + document.getElementById('pergunta').value +'\n' + bot + rand; // O caractere ->   \ n   <-  é usado para encontrar um caractere de nova linha. percebi q ele faz com que apareça as duas linhas ao usuário, a linha de pergunta do user e resposta do bot

      } 

    else if (input.indexOf('/cmd') != -1)
      {
        document.getElementById('resposta').value = 'Comandos :  \n /temp pega uma cidade e mostrar sua temperatura  \n /falas fica falando sozinho por um tempo \n /date mostra a data e a hora atual \n /encomenda redireciona para o meu site de pesquisa de encomenda \n /calc redireciona para a calculadora *Alguns estão em teste e outros ainda estão sendo desenvolvidos*';
      }

    else if (input.indexOf('quero remarcar o dia') != -1 || input.indexOf('quero fazer o pagamento') != -1 || input.indexOf('quero agendar o dia do meu serviço') != -1 || input.indexOf('quero gerar um boleto') != -1 || input.indexOf('quero saber qunado meu serviço vai estar pronto') != -1 || input.indexOf('quero falar com um atendente') != -1)
      {
        document.getElementById('resposta').value +='\n'+ user + document.getElementById('pergunta').value +'\n'+ bot + padrao;
      }

    else if (input.indexOf('não quero falar por aqui') != -1 || input.indexOf('quero falar com uma pessoa') != -1|| input.indexOf('to ok') != -1)
      {
        document.getElementById('resposta').value +='\n'+ user + document.getElementById('pergunta').value +'\n'+ bot + resp_padrao ;
      }

      else if (input.indexOf('tudo bem') != -1 || input.indexOf('tudo certo') != -1|| input.indexOf('eai') != -1|| input.indexOf('eai') != -1)
        {
          document.getElementById('resposta').value +='\n'+ user + document.getElementById('pergunta').value +'\n'+ bot + formal;
        }

        else if (input.indexOf('te fez') != -1 || input.indexOf('te criou') != -1|| input.indexOf('te programou') != -1|| input.indexOf('eai') != -1)
          {
            document.getElementById('resposta').value +='\n'+ user + document.getElementById('pergunta').value +'\n'+ bot + 'Foi o Desenvolvedor Wilhams';
          }

    else if (input.indexOf('qual seu nome?') != -1 || input.indexOf('se chama') != -1 )
      {
        document.getElementById('resposta').value +='\n'+ user + document.getElementById('pergunta').value +'\n'+ bot + 'Sou uma assitente virtal e me chamo Natália';
      }

      else if (input.indexOf('1') != -1) 
      {
        document.getElementById('resposta').value +='\n'+ user + document.getElementById('pergunta').value +'\n'+ bot + 'Seu serviço foi agendado para o dia 30/05/2022.';
      }

      else if (input.indexOf('2') != -1) 
      {
        document.getElementById('resposta').value +='\n'+ user + document.getElementById('pergunta').value +'\n'+ bot + 'Seu serviço estará pronto no dia 30/05/2022.';
      }

      else if (input.indexOf('3') != -1) 
      {
        document.getElementById('resposta').value +='\n'+ user + document.getElementById('pergunta').value +'\n'+ bot + 'Seu serviço foi marcado para o dia 30/05/2022.';
      }

      else if (input.indexOf('4') != -1) 
      {
        document.getElementById('resposta').value +='\n'+ user + document.getElementById('pergunta').value +'\n'+ bot + 'Seu boleto foi gerado para o dia 30/05/2022.';
      }

      else if (input.indexOf('5') != -1) 
      {
        document.getElementById('resposta').value +='\n'+ user + document.getElementById('pergunta').value +'\n'+ bot + 'Em alguns instantes um de nossos atendentes falará com você';
      }

    else if (input.indexOf('/temp') != -1)
      {
        temperatura();
      }
    else if (input.indexOf('/falas') != -1)
      {
        fala_sozinho();
      }

    else if (input.indexOf('/date') != -1)
      {
        data_atual();
      }

    else if (input.indexOf('/encomenda') != -1) //redireciona
        {
          window.open('https://hix3nn.000webhostapp.com/correios.html')
        }

    else if (input.indexOf('/calc') != -1) //redireciona
          {
            window.open('https://hix3nn.000webhostapp.com/calculadora.html')
          }

    else if (input.indexOf('/clear') !=-1)// apagar
    {
      document.getElementById('resposta').value = null;
    }

    else
      {
        document.getElementById('resposta').value += '\n' + user + document.getElementById('pergunta').value +'\n'+bot+ resp_padrao;
      }

  }
```

Código Css:

```
body{
 background-color:#596275;
}

h1{
 color: #3dc1d3;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: arial;
 margin-top: 180px;
}

#pergunta{
 background-color:  #303952;
 border-color: #3dc1d3;
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 filter: drop-shadow(10px 10px 10px #303952);
 color:red;
 height:40px;
 width: 476px;
 font-family: arial;
 }


#resposta{
  height: 400px;
  width: 476px;
  background-color:  #303952;
  border-color: #3dc1d3;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  filter: drop-shadow(10px 10px 10px #303952);
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: arial;
  margin-top: -140px;
}
#mudarcor{
  display: block;
} 
button{
 background-color: #303952;
 color: #3dc1d3;
  border-color: #3dc1d3;
  height: 35px;
  width: 100px;
}

  #pergunta:hover{
 filter: drop-shadow(8px 8px 10px #3dc1d3);
}

button:hover{
 filter: drop-shadow(8px 8px 10px #3dc1d3);
}
```

Já tentei alterar as cores pelo CSS, tanto na id pergunta como na id resposta, na id pergunta só altera a cor enquanto a pergunta está no input depois que é enviada ela adota a cor da tag textarea, já tentei mudar pelo javascript e também só muda a cor no input, depois que é enviado ele adota a cor do input, e tentei mudar a cor da id reposta e ele muda todas as cores do texto dentro do input deixando tanto o texto do usuário como o texto do bot na mesma cor. 
Qual seria a lógica pra fazer isso?

Comment: Nesse caso só o CSS resolve, é só colocar os textos dentro de elementos HTML com classes distintas por exeplo: `<div class="pergunta">Oi</div><div class="resposta">Olá</div>` e no CSS você estiliza como preferir.

Comment: Como faço isso na tag textarea? não dá pra colocar divs diferente na tag textarea

Comment: Tentei várias formas mas infelizmente sem sucesso, o jeito que você disse não funcionou ou estou fazendo errado, os valores enviados pelo usuário e a resposta do bot se juntam na mesma tag dentro do JS, mesmo que altere no css quando enviados os texto vão juntos e com a cor da id que está enviado, a id que está enviado é a id resposta, então teria que ver uma forma de alterar a cor depois de enviado, alguma função que fizesse isso, tentei colocar uma função dentro desse if mas não mudou a cor depois que envia.. Teria que ter alguma forma de alterar a id pergunta que foi enviada pela id reposta

Comment: No textarea não dá mesmo. O textarea é um elemento para a entrada de dados, não para exibição. Para exibir use um div por exemplo. E ao invés de jogar as mensagens no textarea jogue neste div.

Comment: Exatamente o textarea recebe dados, por isso que tõ usando ele, uma div não recebe dados ou recebe? tentei inserir valores na div do jeito que vc falou mas não funciona, o código se trata de um chat e os valores recebidos são enviado juntos para a id do textarea, automaticamente todo o texto dentro dele se torna da cor do id dele, mesmo que seja alterado via css antes, depois que os dados são compilados, eles adquirem a cor da id em questão... teria que haver uma forma de mudar esses valores depois de enviados,

Comment: Edite a pergunta e postando o código completo, assim fica melhor pra te ajudar.

Comment: Editei TiagoA.. :D

Comment: Poderia me dá pelo menos uma luz de como fazer? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando você tem um `textarea`, você tem um elemento de entrada de dados. O `textarea` age semelhante ao `input`.

Para por duas cores diferentes no textarea, você precisaria ter mais de um elemento dentro do textarea o que não é possível pois o valor dele só aceita texto puro, ele não pode ter outros elementos HTML dentro dele.

Para isso você deve usar qualquer outro elemento HTML que não seja um input: um div, span, li...

Vamos usar o `div` no seu caso.
Troque o `textarea` por div:

```html
<div style="font-size: 20px;" cols="50" rows="200" id="resposta">
Olá me chamo Natália e sou sua assistente virtual, como posso te ajudar? (para os comandos digita /cmd)
</textarea>
```

Em todas as linhas que você manipulava o valor do textarea mude para innerHTML. Vou pegar a primeira ocorrência como exemplo:

```js
document.getElementById('resposta').innerHTML = user + document.getElementById('pergunta').value + '\n' + bot + rand;
```

Agora para poder alternar as cores você teria que separar os blocos de textos em elementos distintos. Para isso englobe o valor da pergunta em um elemento e a resposta em outro:

```js
document.getElementById('resposta').innerHTML = '<div>' + user + document.getElementById('pergunta').value + '</div><div>' + bot + rand + '</div>';
```

Atribua uma classe para cada um e depois estilize no CSS:

```js
document.getElementById('resposta').innerHTML = '<div class="usuario">' + user + document.getElementById('pergunta').value + '</div><div class="bot">' + bot + rand + '</div>';
```

```css
.bot {
  width: 70%;
  float: right;
  background-color: #3dc1d3;
}
.usuario {
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #596275;
}
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela disponibilidade de sentar e analisar o código e me dá uma resposta. :)

Comment: Por nada, estou aqui para ajudar. Caso minha resposta tenha resolvido seu problema, você clicar no ✅ ao lado dela para sinalizar que sua pergunta foi respondida.

Comment: Resolveu sim, :D (Clikei)